# how to determine filesize of all object ((images, css, objects and scripts)) defined inside a html page

Tags: php

Is there way to determine filesize of html file 
forexample i have a url

http://url/item/id/1

can i determine the size of files when this url is loaded

I want to show in page 256 Kb loaded in 0.268 seconds at the end of page

try updates

on localhost/testing/index.php

```
echo filesize("http://localhost/testing/testing.html");
```

on localhost/testing/testing.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <img src="test.jpg"/>
    </body>
</htm>
```

on apache error.log

```
 [Fri Dec 31 14:46:05 2010] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat
 failed for http://localhost/testing/testing.html in /var/www/testing/index.php 
 on line 4
```

on index.php if i do

```
echo filesize("/var/www/testing/testing.html");
```

then i get 80 bytes that is without any image

Comment: You're trying to display how long your PHP page took to load (including all image/css/object/script dependencies) on the page?

Comment: @Mathhew yes and i am using zend framework and if i calculate time before application run and after application run then i think i will get the time but not sure about the page

Comment: Maybe the title could be changed according to the real question (how long does my PHP page take to load (including all image/css/object/script dependencies) on the page?).

Comment: You can't tell how long it took to load the entire page from the PHP side — the PHP will generate an HTML document and serve it to the client, which will download images, scripts, etc in response. The PHP program will have finished before everything has finished downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to hold your page render in a buffer (using ob_start()) and then parse it prior to flushing the buffer:

1) You'll want to save the buffer contents prior to rendering using ob_get_contents() (obviously this won't work if you haven't triggered the output buffer using ob_start()) (just to avoid having to call ob_get_contents() multiple times).

2) Check the size of the buffer using strlen($varname), unless you're using mbchar types (unicode) in your HTML, then you'll have to look at alternate methods.

3) Then, parse the buffer for any external CSS files or img tags (should be do'able with a single regex search).

4) Iterate through the list of external CSS files and img tags and get their individual file sizes.

5) Add the CSS and img file sizes to the buffer size and there you go. Total file size.

(Note that anything else that incurs an HTTP request would also have to be calculated)

Simply getting filesize for testing.html won't give you all the data you're looking for (unfortunately), as it only calculates the size of the given file; not any of its contents.

I'd be willing to bet that there's already something out there floating on the OS wagon somewhere that would do most (if not all) of this for you.

Comment: Odd... Pretty sure that's how you would go about calculating the total file size.. And yet, a -1 :P

Comment: @explorex definitely NOT a silly question. and a pretty good answer.

Comment: @abel yup!! but i did not try it